# Image with expanding middle

Tags: html, image, expand, image-size

I want to have a small, either 1 or 2 pixel line down part of the middle of my page to seperate navigation text from content. I want the line to fade to the background color (okay, just fade transparent) at the top and bottom of the line, but I want the middle, solid black part of the line, to expand with the size of the content div on the right.

Is that confusing to read, do I need to elaborate?

EDIT: I've done everything with a table now, I figure that'll be easier. Now my problem is getting the middle part of the line to expand with the other table cell named "content". Everything works with the exception of the sep_mid cell, because I don't want to set a fixed height for the cell, I want it to size based on the "content" cell.

Here's my code:

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <table align="center">
            <tr>
                <td class="nav" rowspan="3"><p>test</p></td>
                <td class="sep_top" rowspan="1"></td>
                <td class="content" rowspan="3"><p>Content here!</p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr> <td class="sep_mid" rowspan="1"></td> </tr>
            <tr> <td class="sep_bot" rowspan="1"></td> </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: #bbc2c7;
    background-image: url('/images/bg.png');
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

body p {
    font-family: Delicious;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "Delicious";
    src: url('/fonts/delicious.ttf');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "Delicious";
    src: url('/fonts/delicious_bold.ttf');
    font-weight: bold;
}

#wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1000px;
}

#wrapper p {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: Delicious;
}

.nav {
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

.sep_top {
    background-image: url('/images/sep_top.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    float: left;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    width: 1px;
    height: 15px;
}

.sep_mid {
    background-color: #000;
    float: left;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    width: 1px;
}

.sep_bot {
    background-image: url('/images/sep_bot.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    width: 1px;
    height: 15px;
}

.content {
    padding-left: 20px;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table td {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Comment: Consider using http://jsfiddle.net to give us a working example?

Comment: Here's a jsfiddle.net example:
http://jsfiddle.net/8s8p8/

Answer (score 0):

I think the empty table cells should contain at least some content, even if it's just `&nbsp;`